# Is it normal to setup both Google and OpenDNS together?

Tags: opendns, google-public-dns

I'm planning to change my ISP DNS on home ADSL-router to Google/OpenDNS. Wouldn't it be better for my internet connection, if I setup **both** Google and OpenDNS like

> Primary DNS: 8.8.8.8
>
> Secondary DNS: 208.67.222.222

Could this create some kind of problem?

Comment: You’re not setting up both. You’re setting up a fallback. Unless Google DNS goes down (ie. never), your PC won’t ask Open DNS. Unless you have an exotic DNS resolver.

Comment: @DanielB are you sure about "never"? [google down](http://www.praguemorning.cz/google-czech-republic) this is just one example that affected me lately. It took some time (hour or two) and it could be longer. But local ISPs rerouted google services to another servers nearby. Google is not some god, they make mistakes, and have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it cause a problem: **Probably Not**

Will it be faster: **Probably Not**

Will it be more reliable: **Unlikely**, unless Google DNS is down or a firewall is blocking you.

Can you do it? **Sure you can**

Any advantages? **Possibly**. If Google is unable to resolve a certain domain name, having both DNS servers as Google ones means you can never resolve it. On the other hand, having different ones means a greater chance of getting it resolved.

Practically, it won't make much of a difference. The secondary DNS server is a fallback in case the primary one fails. You won't be sending requests to this server unless the primary can't resolve, which is rare for Google.

Answer (score 2):

It will causes service inconsistency at very rare occasions but certainly **not** anything that one can classify as problem. What happens is: When Google's DNS server is down (something that I have never seen) you'll notice a difference in how parked domains and 404 pages are resolved.

OpenDNS other services that are activated by using its DNS server but you must sign up for them.